# Cannot connect to Google App Engine Remote API

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to do access my data from my local machine by following this guide:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

I have folowed the guide and changed the web.xml, deployed the code, installed the cloud sdk, run the "gcloud init" command and selected the project but when running the sample code I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to acquire Google Application Default credential.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions.useApplicationDefaultCredential(RemoteApiOptions.java:169)
    at androidlost_remote.RemoteTest.main(RemoteTest.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:98)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions.useApplicationDefaultCredential(RemoteApiOptions.java:164)
    ... 1 more
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller;
import com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions;

public class RemoteTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions().server("myappid-hr.appspot.com", 443).useApplicationDefaultCredential();
        RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
        installer.install(options);
        try {
            DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
            System.out.println("Key of new entity is " + ds.put(new Entity("Hello Remote API!")));
        } finally {
            installer.uninstall();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

UPDATE:

Now the credential seems to be fixed. However now the stacktrace returns a 302:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 302 Found
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1070)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.OAuthClient.get(OAuthClient.java:64)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.getAppIdFromServer(RemoteApiInstaller.java:413)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.loginImpl(RemoteApiInstaller.java:376)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.login(RemoteApiInstaller.java:337)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.install(RemoteApiInstaller.java:173)
    at androidlost_remote.RemoteTest3.main(RemoteTest3.java:16)
```

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852279/when-use-gae-remote-error-occured-com-google-appengine-repackaged-com-google-a) it occurs when the server has not got the remote api in web.xml but I have done that. Anything else I need on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Credential, give it right IAM access, download the json and finally use it before using the api. :)

```
Make sure remote API is enabled

<servlet>
<display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

RemoteApiOptions raoptions = new RemoteApiOptions() .server("my-module-dot-my-project.appspot.com", 443) .useServiceAccountCredential("my-service-account-id", "my-p12-file.p12");
```

read more [here](http://varunsweblog.appspot.com/posts/how-to-use-google-appengine-remote-api-for-java)

Comment: Any hints on how to use the json? Like a tutorial or some sample code? The only samples I can find uses the gcloud library and not appengine.

Comment: RemoteApiOptions raoptions = new RemoteApiOptions()
                .server("my-module-dot-my-project.appspot.com", 443)
                .useServiceAccountCredential("my-service-account-id", "my-p12-file.p12");

Comment: http://varunsweblog.appspot.com/posts/how-to-use-google-appengine-remote-api-for-java

Comment: Thanks - that fixed the credentials problem. Now on to the 302 :-)

Comment: if you think this helped then how about a vote up :)

Comment: Yeah - I was just waiting and hoping someone could explain the 302 - but apparently lots of other have the same problem. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: How do you specify the application to use your JSON file please? I know this may be a silly question, but am struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's break down the error code. The first line of the error code: `Failed to acquire Google Application Default credential.` Tells you what's not working right (couldn't get the GAD credential).

The next line of note is: `at androidlost_remote.RemoteTest.main(RemoteTest.java:14)`. This tells you that the error was caused on line 14 of the `remoteTest` class.

Line 14 is `installer.install(options);`. This points back to your `RemoteApiOptions options` variable. Be sure that the `.options()` arguements point to the correct webserver and port.

Back to the error code now, line 4 straight up tells you why it happened: a `java.io.IOException`. It says this happened because `They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell.` All of which I'm guessing you don't have. So the error code tells you what you need to do and where to go for help. You need to install Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell.

Either you install one/all of those, *or* the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials

From line 4 of the error code: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information